# FreeBSD: Implicit declaration of getpagesize with _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L defined.

Tags: c, posix, freebsd, posix-api

I am currently porting some OS related function of a software project from Linux to FreeBSD. Thereby, I recognized the following problem using `getpagesize` if  `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`is defined on FreeBSD 10.1.

I created a small test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i = getpagesize(); 

        return 0;
}
```

If I compile is using

```
cc test.c -o test
```

it compiles without any warnings. But if I define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` (result of the proper POSIX definition of `getline` function which I need in other parts of the code) I get:

```
cc test.c -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
test.c:5:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getpagesize' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int i = getpagesize(); 
                ^
```

Although I included `unistd.h` as stated in the manpage of `getpagesize`. How can I make the code compiling without warnings with still defined `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is a wrong define. You need the `_XOPEN_SOURCE`. For example:

```
cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 test.c
```

or

```
cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 test.c
```

The `600` and `700` signify version of the Single Unix Specification (SUS for short, aka Open Group Specification, aka POSIX) your application expects from the system library. [See here for the SUSv7.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html)

(2) BUT. That might still not work, because the [`getpagesize()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getpagesize&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) is a BSD-specific function, which actually might be hidden if you try to compile the file in the POSIX-compliance mode.

Normally you need nothing special to get access to the BSD functions on a BSD system, but portable way is to provide the `_BSD_SOURCE` define.

The more portable, POSIX-compliant way to get the page size is  [`sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html) function. [FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysconf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

P.S. Do not have a BSD at hand to test it.

Comment: I tried replacing the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` by `_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` and it works. But using `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600/700` which corresponds to the POSIX 2001/2008 standard the same warning pops up again. Replacing it via `sysconf` is a workaround which does not solve the reason of the problem.

Comment: The `sysconf()` is not a workaround. It is part of POSIX - `getpagesize()` is not. If you want/need POSIX, then you have to use the `sysconf()`.